Horror movie where an eye is rolling down a corridor
This might be a tough one. I'm trying to remember a movie I saw part of when I was younger. The only thing I recall is a guy possibly strapped to a chair and having one of his eyes removed, and later, his eye rolling down a corridor.

Hi, welcome to SF&F.  Was there magic involved?  Like, perhaps he was still able to see though the eye, or he is directing how the eye moves, or something like that?  Not all horror movies are on-topic here, only ones with a fantasy or science fiction component.

Minority Report has moments like that, but it's not a horror movie

In Demolition Mas an eyeball is speared on a pen, but I don't recall if it rolls down a corridor

I'm with @aherocalledFrog - this is Minority Report, and frankly, that part of the movie can feel like horror, not helped by Peter Stormare chewing on the walls (clip on Youtube - https://youtu.be/xgShXWPDJDo?si=xh8P1AEFVraExkEW )
